# GitPython - git add - error - file not recognised

Tags: python, git, addition, commit, gitpython

I am facing problems when trying to add a specific filename to a commit. I can get it working via --all or u=True etc. but when I state the specific name within the command, it gives me the following error:

**raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git add 
  stderr: 'fatal: pathspec '' did not match any files'**

When I copy out and paste the cmd line and paste it into git bash however, it works fine. Is this a functionality problem?

Code below:

```
repo.git.checkout('master')  
repo.git.pull 
repo.git.checkout('Test_20191102c') 
repo.git.add(u=False,'Database/Tables/dbo.daletesttable.sql')
repo.git.add('Database/Tables/dbo.daletesttable.sql') 
repo.git.commit('-m', 'test automation git python 001')
repo.git.push('--set', '-upstream', 'origin', 'Test_20191102c')
```

Full stacktrace:

> Repo at C:\sdw successfully loaded.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/%hiddenpath%/dev2test.py", line 158, in 
>       repo.git.add('SDW/Database/Tables/dbo.daletesttable.sql')
>
> File "C:/%hiddenpath%\cmd.py", line 551, in 
>       return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:/%hiddenpath%\cmd.py", line 1010, in _call_process
>       return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
>
> File "C:/%hiddenpath%\cmd.py", line 821, in execute
>       raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
>
> git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
>
> cmdline: git add Database/Tables/dbo.daletesttable.sql
>
> stderr: 'fatal: pathspec 'Database/Tables/dbo.daletesttable.sql' did
>   not match any files'

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace

Comment: I have edited the full stacktrace into the question